# How to sort object inside of array based on createdAt in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to sort the products array based on the createdAt date.

My orders model

```
const itemSchema = new Schema(
    {
        productId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            max: [10, 'Only 10 quantity of one item can be added.'],
            required: true,
        },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

const ordersSchema = new Schema({
    products: [itemSchema],
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});
```

I tried this according to a stack overflow post

```
 const orders = await Order.findOne({ userId: req.userId })
        .sort({ 'products.createdAt': -1 })
        .slice('products', 10)
        .populate({ path: 'products.productId', select: 'images title' });
```

But it does not return sorted array.

Comment: Then what documents array did you get? You want to sort the `products` subdocuments array, right?

Comment: I got this instead:
{
  products: [
    {
      quantity: 1,
      price: 7699,
      createdAt: 2023-07-17T04:16:04.088Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-07-17T04:16:04.088Z
    },
    {
      quantity: 4,
      price: 7699,
      createdAt: 2023-07-18T05:11:34.621Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-07-18T05:11:34.621Z
    },
    {
      quantity: 1,
      price: 179,
      createdAt: 2023-07-17T05:11:34.622Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-07-17T05:11:34.622Z
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @LinDu yes i want to sort the products array

Comment: There is no `createdAt` field in your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run current version (6.0) of MongoDB, then you can use [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      products: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$products",
          sortBy: { createdAt: 1 }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GHxYIGpeIg8)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "products.createdAt": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$_id",
      products: {
        "$push": "$products"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FFGMTiL3FZF)

Input:

```json
[
  {
    userId: "1",
    products: [
      {
        productId: "1",
        createdAt: "2023-07-02"
      },
      {
        productId: "2",
        createdAt: "2023-07-01"
      },
      {
        productId: "3",
        createdAt: "2023-07-03"
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "products": [
      {
        "createdAt": "2023-07-03",
        "productId": "3"
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2023-07-02",
        "productId": "1"
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2023-07-01",
        "productId": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

Mongoose(v7.3.4) example :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    images: [],
});
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        productId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    },
    { timestamps: true },
);
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

const ordersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    products: [itemSchema],
});
const Orders = mongoose.model('Orders', ordersSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        await Promise.all([Product, Item, Orders].map((m) => m.collection.drop()));
        // seed
        const [p1, p2, p3] = await Product.create([
            { title: 'product a', images: ['a', 'b'] },
            { title: 'product b', images: ['c', 'd'] },
            { title: 'product c', images: ['e', 'f'] },
        ]);
        const items = await Item.create([
            { productId: p1, createdAt: new Date(2023, 6, 4) },
            { productId: p3, createdAt: new Date(2023, 6, 3) },
            { productId: p2, createdAt: new Date(2023, 6, 5) },
        ]);
        const [o1] = await Orders.create([{ products: items }]);

        // test
        const r = await Orders.aggregate()
            .match({ _id: o1?._id })
            .unwind('products')
            .lookup({
                from: 'products',
                localField: 'products.productId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'lookup_products',
            })
            .unwind('lookup_products')
            .addFields({ 'products.title': '$lookup_products.title', 'products.images': '$lookup_products.images' })
            .sort({ 'products.createdAt': -1 })
            .group({ _id: '$_id', products: { $push: '$products' } })
            .project({ lookup_products: 0 });

        console.log(util.inspect(r, false, null));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64b4e66fdafc40c3caae9ee5"),
    products: [
      {
        productId: new ObjectId("64b4e66edafc40c3caae9eda"),
        _id: new ObjectId("64b4e66fdafc40c3caae9ee1"),
        createdAt: 2023-07-04T16:00:00.000Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-07-04T16:00:00.000Z,
        __v: 0,
        title: 'product b',
        images: [ 'c', 'd' ]
      },
      {
        productId: new ObjectId("64b4e66edafc40c3caae9ed9"),
        _id: new ObjectId("64b4e66fdafc40c3caae9edf"),
        createdAt: 2023-07-03T16:00:00.000Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-07-03T16:00:00.000Z,
        __v: 0,
        title: 'product a',
        images: [ 'a', 'b' ]
      },
      {
        productId: new ObjectId("64b4e66edafc40c3caae9edb"),
        _id: new ObjectId("64b4e66fdafc40c3caae9ee0"),
        createdAt: 2023-07-02T16:00:00.000Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-07-02T16:00:00.000Z,
        __v: 0,
        title: 'product c',
        images: [ 'e', 'f' ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```